# Class and ID selectors not functioning properly in HTML

Tags: css, html

I have an interesting problem. The class and id selectors have no effect on my code when **I** type them (the text "I am different" does not turn blue), but when I copy and paste the SAME EXACT CODE from a website such as w3schools.com, the code executes. For instance, look at this code.

```
<!Doctype html> 
<html>
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>My First Page</title>
<style>
p#p01 {
    color:blue;
}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<p id=“p01">I am different</p>
</body>

</html>
```

This works fine when I copy the statements "p id ="p01" and "p#p01" from an external source and paste it into textEdit on my Mac. However if I even just delete the 'p' from "p01" and then RETYPE IT, the text does not turn blue anymore and I have to recopy the statements from an external source. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You might wanna check that you always use utf-8 encoding when writing your file. Also, Jad Jourban's answer.

Comment: what text editor are you using? Smart quotes aren't automatically inserted unless you're using something like word, which would be an inappropriate tool for authoring HTML.

Comment: As stated, I am using textEdit on Mac. Also, why was my question down voted? Is there anything in the future I can fix to make the question more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `opening quote character`: “
it needs to be a regular double quote character: "

It's because textEdit is not meant for editing code. However you can fix this. Check the following link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/quotes-problem-in-mavericks-or-textedit

Comment: Ok that is the problem. However, on my keyboard, every time I use the double quote, it is printed on the screen as a opening quote. How do I prevent this from happening? Also, why was my question down voted? Is there anything in the future I can fix to make the question more clear?

Comment: I just removed the quotes altogether to see the program run correctly, however I know this is bad practice.

Comment: @SKala I updated the answer. I didn't downvote it, but I guess someone did because you assumed that it's the "SAME EXACT CODE". Usually people who leave. Whenever you think that it's the same exact code, then there's probably something wrong that you don't notice. Sometimes the issue is a wrong case for 1 letter and your code is screwed: `classList` and `classlist`

Comment: Wow thank you so much! You have been an awesome help.  I will be sure not to assume its the same code next time!